# android changeCursor() not taking effect

Tags: android, cursor

I am learning android programming and I am writing a small SQL to list app to get "comments" out of DB and put them on a list using a custom CursorAdapter. It all seems to be functional BUT on add/delete the list doesn't repopulate  (delete seems to not function at all). I am calling changeCursor() but it does not appear as though my list updates. After a fresh run I can see the results of the previous run. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Here is my code:

CommentsDataSource.java:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CommentsDataSource {

private MySQLiteHelper SQLhelper;
private SQLiteDatabase database;

public CommentsDataSource (Context context) {
    // Create a link to database:
    SQLhelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
}

public void open() throws SQLException {
    database = SQLhelper.getWritableDatabase();
}
public void close () {
    database.close();
}

public Comment createComment (String comment) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_COMMENT, comment);

    long id = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS, null, values);
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS + " WHERE " + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + id, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Comment newComment  = new Comment();
    newComment.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
    newComment.setComment(cursor.getString(1));

    cursor.close();
    return newComment;
}

public void deleteComment (Comment comment) {
    long id = comment.getId();
    System.out.println("Comment deleted with id: " + id);
    database.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID
            + " = " + id, null);

}

public List<Comment> getAllComments () {
    List<Comment> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    Comment newComment  = new Comment();

    while (! cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        newComment.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
        newComment.setComment(cursor.getString(1));
        list.add(newComment);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    cursor.close();
    return list;
}

public Cursor getCursor() {
    List<Comment> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS, null);
    return cursor;
}
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private CommentsDataSource dataSource;
private Context context;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.context= this;

    dataSource = new CommentsDataSource(this);
    dataSource.open();

    List<Comment> values = dataSource.getAllComments();

    /*ArrayAdapter<Comment> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Comment>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);*/

    Cursor cursor = dataSource.getCursor();
    ListView lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    CustomCursorAdapter adapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(this, cursor);
    lvItems.setAdapter(adapter);


}
public void onClick(View view) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Cursor cursor = dataSource.getCursor();

    CustomCursorAdapter adapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(context, cursor);
    Comment comment = null;
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.add:
            String[] comments = new String[] { "Cool", "Very nice", "Hate it" };
            int nextInt = new Random().nextInt(3);
            // save the new comment to the database
            comment = dataSource.createComment(comments[nextInt]);
            break;
        case R.id.delete:
            if (adapter.getCount() > 0) {
                Cursor d = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(0);
                comment = new Comment();
                comment.setComment(d.getColumnName(1));

                dataSource.deleteComment(comment);
            }
            break;
    }

    Cursor newcursor = dataSource.getCursor();
    adapter.changeCursor(newcursor);

}

}
```

customCursorAdapter:

```
public class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c, 0);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView type = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.setType_textView);
    TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.exerciseName_textView);

    name.setText(cursor.getString(1));
}
}
```

Comment: In `onClick()`, you're creating a new `Adapter` that's never set on the `ListView`, so that's why you don't see changes until restarting. Make your `adapter` a field, initialize it in `onCreate()`, and use the same one everywhere. Your `deleteComment()` method isn't working because you delete by ID in your `CommentsDataSource`, but the `Comment` you pass that method never has an ID set on it. As a side note, you might look into using the Loader framework with a `CursorLoader`. It would move all the db stuff off the main thread, and make updates a little easier.

Comment: Oh YEA! The adapter thing worked perfectly! I have to see how to fix the delete now...thanks!